Can I use deref as part of a method chain?
Is there some way to use the deref operator * as part of a method chain?
For example:
let replacement_numbers = HashMap::from([
    ("one", "1"),
    ("two", "2"),
    ("three", "3"),
]);

let number: &str = "one";
let default_number: &str = "0";

let replacement = replacement_numbers // <-- HashMap<&str, &str>
    .get(number)  // <-- Option<&&str>
    .unwrap_or(&default_number)  // <-- &&str
    .to_digit(10) // <-- does not work on &&str, only &str!
    .expect("Should be a number!");

I need to somehow dereference that &&str into a &str before I can call to_digit(10) on it. Is it possible to do that in a method call? I tried using .deref() but that does not work.

Are you sure you can use to_digit on a &str? In std I see only that of char.

My bad, indeed you are right. This is the problem.

Is it best to delete this now, or keep anyway because the question itself (how to dereference in a method chain) is still valid?

The question itself is not valid: example, documentation

@trueequalsfalse: I think you forgot to share the actual playground link that includes the code, that's a raw playground link, no sharing info attached.

@Willem: It's a valid question I guess, but it's not actually a problem to be solved (as mentioned in my answer) thanks to how Rust handles deref semantics calling a method.

@ShadowRanger You are right... Here it is.

That was really helpful, thanks guys! This is me doing day 1 of advent of code, so a long way to go :-P.

Your code would work just fine if str defined to_digit, as Rust will dereference repeatedly to find a method. Problem is, to_digit is a method on char, not str.
For &str (or &&str, or &&&str, etc.), you could use .parse() (possibly annotating replacement or using turbofish to specify the type), or use the from_str_radix functions of the various primitive types, e.g. u32::from_str_radix.
